# Python 2 String check failing on Unicode

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to get a python library to work on my machine, but for some reason the way it's written seems broken.

The library takes two json files as input, one of them called `library.json`, in `library.json`, it does several checks that look like this:

```
def name(self, n):
        if n and isinstance(n, str):
            if re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+', n):
                raise ValueError("Name can only contain alphanumeric   characters, underscores and periods. Name is: {}".format(n))
            if re.match(r'^\d', n):
                raise ValueError("Name cannot start with a number. The name is: {}".format(n))
            self._name = n
        else:
            raise ValueError('Name must be a non-empty string')
```

I'm using a simple `library.json` pulled straight from the documentation:

```
{
    "word_launching_powershell": {"datetime_field": "datetime",
                                  "weight": 10,
                                  "indicators": [{"field": "process", "value": "powershell.exe"},
                                             {"field": "parent_process", "value": "winword.exe"}]

                             }
 }
```

And a simple test file, again taken straight from the documentation:

```
from electus import Electus

# Create some sample data
events = [{
           "process": "winword.exe",
           "parent_process": "explorer.exe",
           "datetime": "2017-10-16T17:15:47.030114"
           },
          {"process": "powershell.exe",
           "parent_process": "winword.exe",
           "datetime": "2017-10-16T17:15:48.030123"
          }]

# The library.json file stores the indicator definitions
# The combinations of indicators are defined in jobs.json
e = Electus(library_conf='library.json', job_conf='jobs.json')

for event in events:
    alerts = e.evaluate_event(event)
    if alerts:
        print(alerts)
```

So, when I run this test script, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_config.py", line 16, in <module>
    lib_def = LibraryDefinition(name='word_launching_powershell', definition=definition)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/electus/library.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.name = name
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/electus/library.py", line 47, in name
    raise ValueError('Name must be a non-empty string')
ValueError: Name must be a non-empty string
```

Doing a bit of debugging, I see it's dying here:

`n = {unicode}u'word_launching_powershell'`

So this looks like an encoding issue to me, what I don't understand is why the whole library would be written with those `isinstance` checks if they would always fail using json files?  Is there any way for me to fix the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up switching all references of `isinstance(n, str)` to `isinstance(n, basestring)` and it worked fine.